# 2d object whose key is the same as the keys of a value in the same object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm still a newbie in typescript and been searching in google about this for almost 2 hours now.

I want to create a type that is an object that will contain multiple values. The key of one value in the object would be the same as the keys of another value in that same object, except this time they will be functions.

Example value of this would be:

```
{
  values: {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  },
  validators: {
    email: () => { /* some function that does something and returns a string */ },
    password: () => { /* some function that does something and returns a string */ },
  }
};
```

In the example above, you see that the keys of `validators` are the same as the keys of `values`,  except `validators` are composed of functions.

I can do:

```
export type Options = {
  values: Record<string, unknown>,
  validators: Record<string, unknown>
};
```

but this is not robust because I want the autocomplete to happen, I want `validators` to be a record which keys are the same as the keys of `values`, except all those are optional and should be functions.

I'm thinking of using generics, but I don't know what to pass to it

```js
type FormValidator<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: (values: Record<string, unknown>) => string;
};

export type FormOptions = {
  values: Record<string, unknown>;
  validators?: FormValidator<this.values>; // WHAT DO I PASS HERE SO THAT IT WILL GET THE KEYS OF VALUES?
};
```

EDIT 1:

One thing that I think works the same as I want this to work is this: [image]

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYDUCGAbAlgEzcRAHgBUA+KAXigG8BYAKCigG0AFKLAOygGsIQ4AMyjEAugC4oACgCUlcgGdgCLgHMA3AwC+m+gwDGcTkqgA3TAFcICyjQZMmEJGiwZJAcncAaew7BoFBQB3RBwPd21dAyMTc2w8AgQbSXhkdHj8IlBIITNLa3IqOkYHSKA

Notice how the autocomplete works, and if you add something else that's not in `values`, it will also throw an error[image] that's basically how I want it but I want it defined in that one type: `type FormOptions`

EDIT 2:

I'm wanting to do this in ReactJS / ReactNative and just plain NodeJS/TypeScript (that is, without using any frameworks)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question right but here's my example using type parameters

[Sample snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=3#code/FDD0oAgSwOwFwKYCcBmBDAxg4tGswhAGID2SAtgAppJrkDCJMKUA5gLJoAOEA3sBAgBtLjToA5OggBcEAM5wksVgF1ZaGAE8A3MAC%20IcBDiauhUbXII8wDEwXEy5CAF4IAHlIVqlzjwQAHogwACZyjt5iDEwsHNwAfAAUJFxwUPay-IIAbmgANgCuCHKyXlRRfrqCLHl4pU4%20dJX6AJTqWq7xfHq6YOBGBXJorNi29nAQKE4AkvAaWK4R5IlZghC5hcXSq2trCORoUHnSAOQnADQCu2uicnIA7mQhpydXgnqXuzV1O9f7h8dEi0XPEThsoCELm9rrcHk9ZECQWD8hDXrsDHoWkA)

```js
// interface
interface FormParamConfigMap {
  [paramName: string]: any;
}

// type parameter
const Form = <FormParamMap extends FormParamConfigMap>(options: {
  values: FormParamMap;
  filter: FormParamMap;
}): any => {};

///// usage

const formIntance = Form({
    values:{
        email:'',
        password:''
    },
    filter:{
        email:()=>'valid',
        password: ()=>'valid'
    }
})
```

Comment: Wow! This is really close to what I wanted but it doesn't error out when I add something in `filter` that is not in `values`. I'll look deeper into this.

Comment: You can playaround more about the generic types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables.
Probably one solution to achieve what you want is to expose the type itself and let the user define it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want compile time type inference (so auto-complete).

In that case we can't use `this` or `typeof`, etc.

And you want pre-defined key set (indexer) which should be shared by both values.

For this, I don't think there is any way other than string literals.

Such as:

```
type RecordKeys = 'email' | 'password';

type Options = {
    values: Record<RecordKeys, string>,
    validators: Record<RecordKeys, (values: RecordKeys) => string>
};

const o: Options = {
    values: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    validators: {
      email: () => { return 'OK'; },
      password: () => { return 'OK'; },
    }
};
```

This guide is very helpful: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures

Comment: This is only applicable when you know the keys of `values`, but that is a variable on its own... What if you don't know that and its dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options here:

Pass all keys as a generic parameter:

```js
type Options<T extends string> = {
    value: Record<T, string>,
    validators: Partial<Record<T, () => string>>
}


type Keys = 'foo' | 'bar'
const options: Options<Keys> = {
    value: {
        foo: '',
        bar: ''
    },
    validators: {
        foo: () => 'foo',
        bar: () => 'bar'
    }
}
```

OR infer the type from function argument

```js
const isValid = <Keys extends string>(options: Options<Keys>) => {}

isValid({
    value: {
        a: 'a',
    },
    validators: {
        a: () => 'a'
    }
}) // ok

isValid({
    value: {
        b: 'a', // error
    },
    validators: {
        a: () => 'a'
    }
}) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgCpQgD2AhQBM0o1gAnBFAcwD4oBeKAbwFgAoKHqANwCGAGwCuEAFxQAShADGSSsWwAaclRoNlXXv2EJiA4ArSSACgMqJhGGfMUqoACgCUzRhWp169LgF8uAZygkFAA0hAgZCwA5ABmSEjRUAA%20UNEARhbRXPLowFBI8MjoknCIqJjhkYwsHNy8gqISbNo6vPFIktHRWvVtUJmUXdl9UL69Oo36hsaSdf08HZIubmkdPa39g8uuTIwZWZtjfoG5FFAIaABqesTMUBhVZPiEJGQeGvSOheUlsEUVR4RND0XaMVj%20ThcS43IT6RzzBrCMRzI46ARdAQbUbjI5TAxGSgmFqjdE7VbRLFHSG%20VwAejpBQA1oEYbcEXjkc1EVtMT0oAzcJRKApqRMkXCCbMSQsoBinGC0lScX56YykEygA)